# The Guys - Logic #1 - Comics

Tags: logical-deduction, logic-grid

> Welcome to the first in a series of quick logic puzzles. The stories behind the puzzles follow 3 guys who are life long friends, went to school together, and now work in the IT field together in Tampa.

[image: Lightning Logic]

So the guys decided to see how their comic collections were doing. They each picked one comic hero to collect: hulk, aquaman, and flash. Individually, they have 10, 20, or 30 in their collection.

**Start Two Minute Timer...**

Charles ( who collects Flash ) has 20 more comics than Anthony, and Anthony isn't the one who collects hulk, or the one with 20 comics.

Based on that statement, who collect what, and how many?

[image: The Guys]

Answer (score 2):

> Charles 30 flash [20 more, must be 30]
> Anthony 10 aquaman
> Michael 20 hulk